# Label Symbology Pie Charts/Multiple Bar Graph

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, chart, graph

I created bar graph and pie charts on every single feature on the basis of their values stored in attribute table but I can't label/plot the values on these graph/on the top of graphs. Currently this could be done by coverting the labels to annotation and then adjusting the location manually, This is really hectic and time taking way. Do we have any option to add/label values on the bar graph/ pie charts?

[image: Bar Graph Symobology in ArcMap]